# Is there a way to draw shape over radio buttons in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

New to react native. I made this screen using radio buttons using the package `react-native-simple-radion-button`. I want to join the selected buttons using lines or something (example attached below) to form a shape. I am also attaching the source code of the screen. What packages should one be using to achieve this? I was looking at some shapes libraries in react native but found myself to be clueless. I think there is also a possibility of using absolute position of items (radio buttons) and using `Style` but I am not sure how to approach through that either.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

import RadioForm from "react-native-simple-radio-button";

import { Content, Card, CardItem, Text } from "native-base";

const NTCPDiamondScreen = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  var technology = [
    { label: "Super-high", value: "Super-high" },
    { label: "High", value: "High" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { label: "Low", value: "Low" },
  ];

  var pace = [
    { label: "Regular", value: "Regular" },
    { label: "Fast", value: "Fast" },
    { label: "Time-critical", value: "Time-critical" },
    { label: "Blitz", value: "Blitz" },
  ];

  var complexity = [
    { label: "Assembly", value: "Assembly" },
    { label: "System", value: "System" },
    { label: "Array", value: "Array" },
  ];

  var novelty = [
    { label: "Derivative", value: "Derivative" },
    { label: "Platform", value: "Platform" },
    { label: "Breakthrough", value: "Breakthrough" },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <Content padder>
        <Card>
          <CardItem header bordered style={{ backgroundColor: "#33CCFF" }}>
            <Text style={styles.textTitleStyle}>Create New Diamond</Text>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem bordered>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
              <View>
                <View
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: 145,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                      fontStyle: "italic",
                      paddingLeft: 30,
                      color: "#B4BFC3",
                    }}
                  >
                    Technology
                  </Text>
                  <RadioForm
                    radio_props={technology}
                    initial={-1}
                    onPress={(value) => {
                      setValue(value);
                      console.log(value);
                    }}
                    buttonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                    buttonSize={10}
                    selectedButtonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                    labelStyle={{
                      fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                      fontSize: 7,
                    }}
                    style={{}}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.secondView}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      marginRight: 10,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                        fontStyle: "italic",
                        paddingLeft: 30,
                        paddingBottom: 5,
                        color: "#B4BFC3",
                      }}
                    >
                      Novelty
                    </Text>
                    <RadioForm
                      radio_props={novelty}
                      initial={-1}
                      formHorizontal={true}
                      labelHorizontal={false}
                      onPress={(value) => {
                        setValue(value);
                        console.log(value);
                      }}
                      buttonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                      buttonSize={10}
                      selectedButtonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                      labelStyle={{
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                        fontSize: 7,
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>

                  <View
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: 40,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                        fontStyle: "italic",
                        paddingLeft: 30,
                        paddingBottom: 5,
                        color: "#B4BFC3",
                      }}
                    >
                      Complexity
                    </Text>
                    <RadioForm
                      radio_props={complexity}
                      initial={-1}
                      formHorizontal={true}
                      labelHorizontal={false}
                      onPress={(value) => {
                        setValue(value);
                        console.log(value);
                      }}
                      buttonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                      buttonSize={10}
                      selectedButtonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                      labelStyle={{
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                        fontSize: 7,
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: 145,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                      fontStyle: "italic",
                      paddingLeft: 30,
                      color: "#B4BFC3",
                    }}
                  >
                    Pace
                  </Text>
                  <RadioForm
                    radio_props={pace}
                    initial={-1}
                    onPress={(value) => {
                      setValue(value);
                      console.log(value);
                    }}
                    buttonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                    buttonSize={10}
                    selectedButtonColor={"#33CCFF"}
                    labelStyle={{
                      fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",

                      fontSize: 7,
                    }}
                    style={{}}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </Content>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  secondView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  textTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: "sans-serif-light",
    color: "#fff",
    paddingLeft: 80,
  },
});

NTCPDiamondScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: () => (
    <Image
      source={require("../../assets/splash_modified.png")}
      style={{
        width: 45,
        height: 45,
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    />
  ),
};

export default NTCPDiamondScreen;
```

How can I achieve this? Need help.

Comment: Study about gesture handling. https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: Using `position :"absolute"` could be a good solution, I imagine you could draw all possible lines (https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native) between each points and hide/appear the selected ones

Comment: Still not sure how to draw as I have different ```RadioForm```s wrapped in separate views. So drawing over them seems weird. Also how can I possibly draw all the images (as required) and hide them and show only the desired ones?